# Instantiate object by type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

I ended up with this code in one of my projects:

```
function foo(type, desc)
{
  var p = new type(desc);
}
```

I am not an expert in JS, can somebody confirm whether it's valid JavaScript or not? It seems to be working fine, with Chrome at least.

type - is a class that is derived from another class, has some functions.
desc - is just an object that keeps properties.

update: yes, type is a constructor: function type(desc) {}

Comment: Sounds like it is valid; why you would want to do this is another matter.

Comment: So long as `type` is a constructor of some sort, your function will work just fine.

Comment: @zzzzBov thank you, exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming `var type = function(foo){...}` **then yes**